# how to use select (col array())from table

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Overloads Function SETData(Table As Tables, Col() As String) As Statuez
    Dim DD As New DataSet, State As New Statuez
    Try
        DD = R.Dset(Table, "Select **col()** from " & Table.TName & " where username='" & Table.User & "'")
        DG.DataSource = DD.Tables(0)
        State.Done = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        State.Done = False
        State.Message = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return State
End Function
```

*** Col() As String is an array holds the names of columns needed

Is there any way to select column array with out typing every member of the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

`Dim result As String = String.Join(",", Col)`

then use the `result` in the `SELECT` statement.

Aside from this, perhaps you should look at parameterizing your statements as it is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: No problem. There are quite a few resources on SO for this type of question, look around first next time :)

Comment: i tried to search but i think i didnot typed the suitable words to search

Comment: No worries! Glad to have helped.